# How to label "xtics" at every second points?

Tags: gnuplot

Hi I am plotting a graph with Gnuplot and using below command.

```
set xrange [0:20]
set xtics 0,0.5
```

The graph and scale are correct as I wanted. But I would like to label only integer points (e.g. 0,1,2,3,4...,20) but I still want to keep tics at every 0.5 interval.

[image]

How can I command for that?
thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minor tics are set with `set mxtics`:

```
set xrange [0:20]
set xtics 0,1
set mxtics 2
```

This plots a single minor tic between two labelled major tics.

If minor and major tics should have the same size use

```
set xtics scale 1,1
```